# Grouping multiple endnotes together

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, enotez

I am using package `enotez` and `hyperref`.

I have multiple endnotes at the end of a sentence. I print the endnotes at the end of the text using `\printendnotes`.

Example: This is the sentence `\endnote{First one}\endnote{Second one}\endnote{Third one}`.

When I compile the endnotes appear as superscript to my text: 1 2 3
I would like them to appear as 1-3.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide us with a minimal example of code we can compile to reproduce the issue. Since you seem to be using LaTeX, this should start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}`. If your note markers are hyperlinked, how would it work with a range?

Comment: Which package do you use for this purpose? Does its manual offer such an option already?

Comment: Should be possible together with `fnpct `